# Swift : Filter in the dictionary that is grouped by key

Tags: swift, dictionary, filter, swiftui

My goal is to be able to filter by name in the dictionary that is grouped by key and to see the results filtered by the text that was inputted in the Search Field. What I stopped at is:

```
var groupedContacts: [String: [CNContact]] {
    .init (
        grouping: store.contacts,
        by: {$0.nameFirstLetter}
    )
}

func filterContactsByName(_ textSearch: String) -> [String: [CNContact]]  {
    let contacts = groupedContacts

    if !textSearch.isEmpty {
        return contacts.compactMapValues{$0.filter {$0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(textSearch)}}.filter{!$0.value.isEmpty}

    } else {
       return contacts
    }
}
```

And then:

```
 List() {
                        ForEach(self.filterContactsByName(searchText).keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
                        Section(header: Text(key).modifier(SectionHeader(backgroundColor: Color.white, foregroundColor: Color.black))) {
                            ForEach(self.groupedContacts[key]!, id: \.self) { contact in
                                HStack {
                                    self.image(for: contact.imageProfile)
                                        .renderingMode(.original)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFill()
                                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .clipShape(Circle())
```

My result:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nde2T.png)

As I understood, I received all the results in the key-group, that's why we see Danial before David. And it will be the same if we input David - we will see Danial.
TIA for a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to both filter out the right group and then filter inside that group. In the below code, which is somewhat simplified since I used String instead of CNContact and didn't bother with case insensitive searching, I first find the group by filtering on the first char of the search string and then I used `reduce(into:)` in combination with `filter` to filter the array for the found key.

```
var groupedContacts: [String: [String]] = ["D": ["David", "Daniel"], "A": ["AAA"]]
let filter = "Dav"

let results = groupedContacts.filter { $0.key == filter.prefix(1) }
    .reduce(into: [:]) {$0[$1.key] = $1.value.filter { $0.hasPrefix(filter)}}
```

Comment: Joakim, thank you it looks awesome! The last thing I would ask you to help is to explain how to get `CNContact.name` in the line `$1.value.filter`. Because in my case here value is `[CNContact]` and not a String

Comment: It's [String] that corresponds to [CNContact] so it is inside the last filter you need to change the code, it should be `$0.name.hasPrefix(filter)`

Comment: Joakim, I really appreciate your help and this works perfectly good until I use it here: `ForEach(self.filterContactsByName(searchText).keys.sorted()`. I use this approach because need to have list that is grouped and sorted when no search is needed. And as I understand `keys.sorted' back me to the point I've started from. But I don't know how to combine both conditions.

Comment: Joakim, the mistake was in my second ForEach loop - I didn't use there filtered list. So, your solution is totally correct. Thanks a lot!